# What does 'opaque object' means in Tensorflow Serving?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I've looked through the official documentation of Tensorflow Serving to understand how does it structured. However, I've encountered one terminology, `opaque object`.

It states, `Tensorflow Serving Core treats servables and loaders as opaque objects`

What does that mean and how does it relate to Tensorflow Serving structure?

Here is the link for the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/architecture_overview)

Comment: This is C terminology. For some explanation you can check the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) on this.